# Keyboard randomly types numbers instead of letters

Tags: keyboard

Randomly, my keyboard types numbers instead of certain letters. For example "Keyboard typing numbers" becomes "2eyb6ard ty-5ng n40bers". After searching on Google I found turning off <kbd>num lock</kbd> fixes the problem but would like a more permanent fix. The keyboard is Dynex and I've tried updating the driver. The keyboard connects through a USB cable.

Comment: do you have another usb keyboard to plug in?

Comment: @Keltari unfortunately not

Comment: Does your Keyboard have a Numpad on the right? It sounds like you have a keyboard that has alt characters for the keys `mjkluio` and possibly more. Can you provide an exact model of your keyboard?

Comment: @MichaelFrank DX-WRK1401 http://www.amazon.com/Dynex-USB-Keyboard-5307516/dp/B00CZPWC40

Comment: I tracked this keyboard down to the manufacturers product page and in the Q&A someone asked this exact question 2 1/2 years ago. It sounds like it might be an issue with this model. My best guess is that it identifies itself as a laptop keyboard for some reason. When you have `num lock` on, does the actual numpad work?

Comment: @MichaelFrank yes when `num lock` is on, the keypad works. Isn't that expected?

Comment: Okay, I was just curious on that part, if the right half of your keyboard works as a numpad, I thought the actual numpad might switch off.

Comment: I also found unplugging and plugging back in the keyboard fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue after upgrading to Win10. My USB keyboard was working fine on Win7, but started acting out with Win10.

The numlock temporary fix was driving me nuts, but I noticed that my husband's keyboard was working fine, and the only difference was that his was a PS2 keyboard. So I took a USB to PS2 adapter and used it with my keyboard, restarted the computer, and now it's working.

I hope this helps you too!